# Is it possible to modify the dimensions of an array while a c# program is running?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, multidimensional-array

You can specify the dimensions of an array using static ints like so:

```
    static int VertRows = 3;
    static int HorRows = 3;
    int[,] gameBoard = new int[VertRows, HorRows];
```

However, I'm assuming that because they are static I will not be able to alter `VertRows` or `HorRows` during runtime? Is there a way to change them when the script starts, or while it's running?

Comment: Arrays have fixed size (this is true even for 1D arrays). But you can always reassign them with a different size: `gameBoard = new int[newHeight, newWidth]`. For dynamic resizing use resizable collections, eg. `List<List<int>>` so every row is a `List<int>`.

Comment: Also `static` != `const`. Array dimensions need not be static, nor const. You can use any variable as size.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of VertRows and HorRows on startup, you can refer to this code:

```
class Program
{
    static int VertRows = 3;
    static int HorRows = 3;
    int[,] gameBoard = new int[VertRows, HorRows];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter  New VertRows");
        VertRows=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter New HorRows");
        HorRows=Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("VertRows is "+VertRows);
        Console.WriteLine("HorRows is "+HorRows);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Refer to [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants) we can see that constants are declared with the const modifier and cannot be changed for the life of the program. But the fields declared by the static modifier can be changed.

Comment: Thank you. What else could they be modified with? It didn't like just standard ints

Comment: @Tiggy Sorry, I made a mistake in my previous answer. After testing it doesn't work. I edited my answer. I am glad to help if you have any others questions. If it can help you, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered.

Comment: Ah! Thanks again, I haven't had a chance to test it yet but I will. :)

Comment: @Tiggy May I know if you have got any chance to check my answer? I am glad to help if you have any others questions.

Comment: Thank you for checking in. Unfortunately I haven't had a chance as I've been buried in other parts of the program. However, there will come a point where I will likely need to try this - so I'll try to get back to you when I do.